# Find the equation of the parabola and sketch the graph

Tags: plotting, functions

Consider the following information: A quadratic function with equation $f(x) = ax^2+ bx + c$  passes through three points,  $A(-1,-1), B(1,-7)$ and $C(3,3)$.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Is this Question about the Software Mathematica? If so please complement your Question with Code. Else [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions) satisfies your needs better.

Comment: ...also, it's generally frowned upon to post homework questions without showing any effort to solve them yourself!

Comment: @ShaunKrant your question would be regarded as either a Mathematics question (i.e. you are on the wrong stackexchange) or if it relates to Mathematica, then this question would be considered as "homework" or "please do" without any effort. The users on this site are diverse, creative and helpful. Your question (as posed)  is unlikely to receive a response. However, even worse, the 'sketch the graph' in the title is aimed at an opportunity for you to learn that without effort from you is lost,

Comment: Jeez, sorry first time using this site, I'm just trying to figure out how to use Mathematica

Comment: @ShaunKrant I am sorry if you feel the comments are unfair or unkind.  Some questions: (i) do the 3 points determine a unique parabola? (ii) if so how would you (pen and paper) work out the equation? Look at `Plot`,`Solve`,`NSolve` in documentation.  Try some code and if you get into trouble it will be easy to help you with Mathematica issue. There are many ways to approach this and Mathematica's versatile (and fun).

Comment: To help you start out: look up `InterpolatingPolynomial[]`.

Answer (score 5):

I post this taking the OP on face value. There are many ways (of course) to do this.
There is a lot to digest (for someone new to Mathematica, esp. distinguishing substance from cosmetic aspects).

Setup:

```
a = {-1, -1};
b = {1, -7} ;
c = {3, 3};
array = {a, b, c};
exp = u x^2 + 2 v x  y + w y^2;
```

1. "Just get Mathematica to do it" (as J.M. suggested `Interpolating polynomial):

   ```
   Expand@InterpolatingPolynomial[array, x]
   ```
2. Plugging in values for x and y and solving 3 equations in 3 unknowns:

   ```
   (exp /. First@
   Solve[{#1^2, #1, 1}.{u, 2 v, w} == #2 & @@@ array, {u, v, w}]) /. y -> 1
   ```
3. Just another way to do the same thing:

   ```
   ca = CoefficientArrays[u x^2 + 2 v x  y + w y^2, {x, y},
   "Symmetric"-True];
   ans = First@With[{m = ca[[3]]},
   Solve[{#1, 1}.m.{#1, 1} == #2 & @@@ array, {u, v, w}]];
   p[n_] := exp /. (ans~Join~{x -> n, y -> 1})
   p[x]
   ```
4. Confirmation plot:

   ```
   Framed@Plot[p[x], {x, -1, 3}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[array], 
   Text[#, #, {0.5, -2}] & /@ array}, 
   PlotLabel -> Rasterize@TraditionalForm[Row[{"y= ", p[x]}]], 
   PlotRangePadding -> {1, 1}, 
   GridLines -> {Range[-2, 4], Range[-8, 4]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
   ```

The out of this code:

[image]

**Comment**

I post this answer as I still recall a certain intimidation when I first started on this site. I acknowledge that this is a "homework" type question. My comments attest to my attempts to direct towards editing the question. Finally, (i) if this is homework then the OP does has lost an opportunity for self directed learning and if it is submitted I suggest a teacher may ask the person submitting to explain how it was done (ii) if it is not homework then, perhaps, it will motivate the user to their own approach or to dissect the code (which to some extent is deliberately opaque- for reasons of (i)

Comment: yet another (maybe simpler?) way to do it: `s = Solve[{-1 == a (-1)^2 + b (-1) + c, -7 == a (1)^2 + b (1) + c, 
   3 == a 3^2 + b*3 + c}, {a, b, c}]
Show[Plot[(a x^2 + b x + c) /. s, {x, -5, 5}], 
 ListPlot[{{-1, -1}, {1, -7}, {3, 3}}]]`

Comment: @mattiav27  thank you. Look at 2.above it is just a different way of coding your approach. Yours is  explicit and (hence) much easier to understand. The 'y' I use was unnecessary but needed for Coefficient Array. The Solve part is identical to yours but saves writing out all equations explicitly. :)